# Buscar imagem a partir de uma lista

Tags: php, vba

Olá, tenho uma lista de aproximadamente 1.000 produtos,  a primeira coluna é o código sku e a segunda é o nome. 
Preciso da imagem deste produtos que são facilmente encontradas no Google pelo código sku.
Existe alguma forma de buscar automaticamente estas imagens no Google a partir de uma lista e fazer o download delas para uma pasta no HD?

Obrigado

Hello, I have a list of about 1.000 products, the first column is the sku code and the second the product name.
I need the image of these products (thumbs in 600x600 dpi or higher) that I can easily find at Google Images
Is there a way to download this images automatically from Google to my hd?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Gustavo, bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Aqui funciona um pouco diferente dos fóruns onde perguntas genéricas são mais aceitas. Poste algo do que você já fez e qual a dúvida técnica em relação a alguma dificuldade que você encontrou. Não há necessidade (e nem deve) de postar em inglês, existe a versão em inglês do [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) para tal.

Comment: E uma dica, não sei se é uma boa ideia baixar automaticamente a imagem pelo SKU, pois pode acabar baixando uma imagem genérica (e incorreta) para o produto, pois você teria que definir para baixar, por exemplo, a primeira imagem encontrada na pesquisa do Google.

Comment: Aproveitando, dê uma lida nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para entender um pouco mais sobre a comunidade StackOverflow.